# How can you filter Snowflake EXPLAIN AS TABULAR syntax when its embedded in the TABLE function? Can you filter it with anything?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table named Posts I would like to count and profile in Snowflake using the current Snowsight UI.
When I return the results via EXPLAIN using TABLULAR I am able to return the set with the combination of TABLE, RESULT_SCAN, and LAST_QUERY_ID functions, but any predicate or filter or column reference seems to fail.

Is there a valid way to do this in Snowflake with the TABLE function or is there another way to query the output of the EXPLAIN using TABLULAR?

```sql
-- Works
EXPLAIN using TABULAR SELECT COUNT(*) from Posts;

-- Works
SELECT t.* FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) as t;

-- Does not work
SELECT t.* FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) as t where operation = 'GlobalStats';
-- invalid identifier 'OPERATION', the column does not seem recognized.
```

Tried the third example and expected the predicate to apply to the function output. I don't understand why the filter works on some TABLE() results and not others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double quote the column name

```
where "operation"=
```

From the [**Documentation**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html#:%7E:text=the%20commands%20use%20delimited%20identifier%20notation%20(double%20quotes))

> Note that because the output column names from the DESC USER command
> were generated in lowercase, the commands use delimited identifier
> notation (double quotes) around the column names in the query to
> ensure that the column names in the query match the column names in
> the output that was scanned